# Getting error while connecting node and mongo as cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

Hello everyone I'm trying to connect mongo and node. But i'm getting cannot GET Please help me with this
My code is as follows. It would be great if someone helps me in resolving this issue
app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/NammaDB');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.log.bind(console, "connection error"));

db.once('open', function(callback) {
    console.log("connection succeeded");
})
var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post('login', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.username;
    var pass = req.body.password;
    var data = {
        "eid": hello,
        "pwd": hello,
    } 
    db.collection('users').insertOne(data, function(err, collection) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Record inserted Successfully");

    });

    return res.redirect('/login.html');
})


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set({
        'Access-control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    return res.redirect('login.html');
}).listen(3000)
console.log("server listening at port 3000");
```

My index.js code is as follows
index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('It works!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: if you are using routes from another file you need to import the route to the main app.js file and then used app.use("/routename", routerImport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you just need to import routes and define middleware in your `root` file

Give your path of `index.js file` here I assume you have `index.js` file inside `routes/index.js`

```
const routes = require('./routes/index')
```

and use middleware like

```
app.use('/get', routes);
```

Now your `URL` looks like `http://localhost:3000/get`